# What is this tissue?

Tags: histology

Does anybody recognize this picture and can tell me what organ it came from? 
[image]

Comment: just in case this is homework.. http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/266/homework-policy-for-faq

Comment: This is not homework. I am creating a software system which will be used in biologic research. This is one of the pictures I might be using in the design, possibly as some sort of background. I am genuinely curious what the pretty daisy-like cells (or multi-cell structures?) are :) and also want to know more about it so I can search for similar images.

Comment: ok - just wanted to check (this is the sort of thing that gets posted a lot from students looking for a quick answer). It's a nice image, good luck

Comment: See Wheater's Functional Histology p. 283 Fig. 14.29e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 3:** Credit should go to @Cornelius and @DMSever for initially identifying the tissue correctly. I incorporated D M Sever's answer into mine (Update 2,below) because his answer is being down voted for brevity, but he is a recognized authority in the field. I'll remove his answer from mine if his answer ends up being retained.

I showed this question to my histological colleague. He suggested that the tissue is most likely a submucosal gland from either the duodenum (Brunner's glands) or the esophagus. My colleague also said that your image is quite similar to submucosal glands in the large intestine but the presence of smooth muscle surrounding the glands eliminates the large intestine.

**Update 1:** My histological colleague forwarded your question to one of *his* histological colleagues. He too said Brunner's gland.

**Update 2:** My histological colleague forwarded your question to his *most trusted* histological colleague. He said colon, specifically the transverse sections through [Crypts of Lieberkuhn](http://medcell.med.yale.edu/histology/gi_tract_lab/crypts_of_lieberkuhn.php). He then signed on as @DMSever and posted a brief but authoritative answer. He's a veteran of histological affairs.

Here's a photo of Brunner's glands in the duodenum, taken from [here](http://achmad-zaifullah.blogspot.com/2011/04/lower-gastrointestinal-tract.html).

[image]

Here's a photo of the esophageal submucosal glands, taken from [here](http://www.vetmed.vt.edu/education/curriculum/vm8304/lab_companion/histo-path/vm8054/labs/Lab18/EXAMPLES/Exesoph3.htm).

[image]

Comment: I know it is your colleague who delivered the final identification, but you are the one who went to the trouble to ask two other people on my behalf, so I give you the accepted answer. I hope your colleague doesn't mind.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not really sure, but it seems like a cross section of intestinal villi / intestinal glands from the large intestine.

Here are some images:

- Jubal Harshaw. [Large intestine villi cross sectioned showing goblet cells_100X_CS0187](http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-20628100/stock-photo-large-intestine-villi-cross-sectioned-showing-goblet-cells-x-cs.html) on ShutterStock
- Jubal Harshaw. [Large intestine villi shown in both longitudinal section and cross section](http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-20628109/stock-photo-large-intestine-villi-shown-in-both-longitudinal-section-and-cross-section.html) on ShutterStock
- Garry DeLong. [Light micrograph of large intestine villi in cross section, showing goblet cells (Magnification x400)](http://www.gettyimages.com/detail/photo/light-micrograph-of-large-intestine-villi-high-res-stock-photography/121820877) on Getty Images
- Hill, M.A. (2014) Embryology Gastrointestinal Tract - Colon Histology. Retrieved September 24, 2014, from https://php.med.unsw.edu.au/embryology/index.php?title=Gastrointestinal_Tract_-_Colon_Histology

And this is one image from the last link:

> Crypts of Lieberkühn - (intestinal gland, intestinal crypt) [...] Transverse
>   [image]

Answer (score 1):

It is from the Colon - transverse sections through crypts of Lieberkuhn seen there.

For references see:

[Wheater's Functional Histology](http://www.elsevier-etextbooks.com/product/wheater) p. 283 Fig. 14.29e

[UNSW Embryology](http://embryology.med.unsw.edu.au/embryology/index.php?title=Gastrointestinal_Tract_-_Colon_Histology).

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. DS said you mentioned a particular text. Would you mind editing your answer to include that reference? Answers on Biology.SE are considered stronger answers with references. Not everyone here will know of your expertise in the field.

Comment: Can you please expand your answer with some references? Actually it is more a comment.

Comment: I think the special "warning" should be removed now. This answer basically contains the same information as the top voted answer minus links to images, and names the specific structure seen in the picture.